# Maven and the " is not a known entity type" error

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, derby

I generated a maven project with the quickstart archetype. So I obtained the following project structure:

```
|-- src
| |-- main
| | |-- java      
| | |-- resources 
| |-- test
| | |-- java      
| | |-- resources 
|-- pom.xml
```

I modified the "pom.xml" file :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.apress.javaee6</groupId>
  <artifactId>chapter02</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>chapter02</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
        <version>10.6.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <version>10.6.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

As you noticed, I work with derby. The "src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml" is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="chapter02PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.apress.javaee6.chapter02.Book</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="DERBY"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/chapter02DB;create=true"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="APP"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="APP"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Then, I created a "Book" Class:

```
package com.apress.javaee6;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "findAllBooks", query = "SELECT b FROM Book b")
public class Book {

    // ======================================
    // =             Attributes             =
    // ======================================
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;
    private Float price;
    @Column(length = 2000)
    private String description;
    private String isbn;
    private Integer nbOfPage;
    private Boolean illustrations;

    // ======================================
    // =            Constructors            =
    // ======================================

    public Book() {
    }

    public Book(String title, Float price, String description, String isbn, Integer nbOfPage, Boolean illustrations) {
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.nbOfPage = nbOfPage;
        this.illustrations = illustrations;
    }

    // ======================================
    // =          Getters & Setters         =
    // ======================================
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }




    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public Integer getNbOfPage() {
        return nbOfPage;
    }

    public void setNbOfPage(Integer nbOfPage) {
        this.nbOfPage = nbOfPage;
    }

    public Boolean getIllustrations() {
        return illustrations;
    }

    public void setIllustrations(Boolean illustrations) {
        this.illustrations = illustrations;
    }

    // ======================================
    // =         hash, equals, toString     =
    // ======================================

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Book");
        sb.append("{id=").append(id);
        sb.append(", title='").append(title).append('\'');
        sb.append(", price=").append(price);
        sb.append(", description='").append(description).append('\'');
        sb.append(", isbn='").append(isbn).append('\'');
        sb.append(", nbOfPage=").append(nbOfPage);
        sb.append(", illustrations=").append(illustrations);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

And, of course, the "Main class":

```
package com.apress.javaee6;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Creates an instance of book
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setId(1231L);
        book.setTitle("The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy");
        book.setPrice(12.5F);
        book.setDescription("Science fiction comedy series created by Douglas Adams.");
        book.setIsbn("1-84023-742-2");
        book.setNbOfPage(354);
        book.setIllustrations(false);

        // Gets an entity manager and a transaction
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("chapter02PU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();

        // Persists the book to the database
        tx.begin();
        em.persist(book);
        tx.commit();

        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

I start the Derby server:

```
./derby/bin/startNetworkServer
```

The problem is when I run the main class:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.apress.javaee6.Main"
```

I get the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] An exception occured while executing the Java class. null

Object: Book{id=null, title='The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy', price=12.5, description='Science fiction comedy series created by Douglas Adams.', isbn='1-84023-742-2', nbOfPage=354, illustrations=false} is not a known entity type.
```

I thought that the problem was the "id=null". But, when I set the Id manually (to 123 for example), I get the same error message. I also tried to use the following anotatations in the Book class:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
```

or

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Anybody has the solution to this error?

PS: Here is the exec command result with error stacktrace turned on:

```
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'exec'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building chapter02
[INFO]    task-segment: [exec:java]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Preparing exec:java
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[INFO] [exec:java {execution: default-cli}]
[EL Finest]: 2010-08-19 13:38:37.215--ServerSession(6419763)--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--Begin predeploying Persistence Unit chapter02PU; session file:/home/zakaria/Dev/chapter02/target/classes/_chapter02PU; state Initial; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: 2010-08-19 13:38:37.243--ServerSession(6419763)--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--property=eclipselink.orm.throw.exceptions; default value=true
[EL Finer]: 2010-08-19 13:38:37.272--ServerSession(6419763)--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--Searching for default mapping file in file:/home/zakaria/Dev/chapter02/target/classes/
[EL Finer]: 2010-08-19 13:38:37.276--ServerSession(6419763)--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--Searching for default mapping file in file:/home/zakaria/Dev/chapter02/target/classes/
[EL Finest]: 2010-08-19 13:38:37.3--ServerSession(6419763)--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--End predeploying Persistence Unit chapter02PU; session file:/home/zakaria/Dev/chapter02/target/classes/_chapter02PU; state Predeployed; factoryCount 0
[EL Finer]: 2010-08-19 13:38:37.3--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--JavaSECMPInitializer - transformer is null.
[EL Finest]: 2010-08-19 13:38:37.3--ServerSession(6419763)--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--Begin predeploying Persistence Unit chapter02PU; session file:/home/zakaria/Dev/chapter02/target/classes/_chapter02PU; state Predeployed; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: 2010-08-19 13:38:37.301--ServerSession(6419763)--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--End predeploying Persistence Unit chapter02PU; session file:/home/zakaria/Dev/chapter02/target/classes/_chapter02PU; state Predeployed; factoryCount 1
[EL Finest]: 2010-08-19 13:38:37.309--ServerSession(6419763)--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--Begin deploying Persistence Unit chapter02PU; session file:/home/zakaria/Dev/chapter02/target/classes/_chapter02PU; state Predeployed; factoryCount 1
[EL Finer]: 2010-08-19 13:38:37.315--ServerSession(6419763)--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--Could not initialize Validation Factory. Encountered following exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Validation
[EL Finest]: 2010-08-19 13:38:37.323--ServerSession(6419763)--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--property=eclipselink.logging.level; value=FINEST; translated value=FINEST
[EL Finest]: 2010-08-19 13:38:37.323--ServerSession(6419763)--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--property=eclipselink.logging.level; value=FINEST; translated value=FINEST
[EL Finest]: 2010-08-19 13:38:37.324--ServerSession(6419763)--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--property=javax.persistence.jdbc.user; value=APP
[EL Finest]: 2010-08-19 13:38:37.324--ServerSession(6419763)--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--property=javax.persistence.jdbc.password; value=xxxxxx
[EL Finest]: 2010-08-19 13:38:37.429--ServerSession(6419763)--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--property=eclipselink.target-database; value=DERBY; translated value=org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.DerbyPlatform
[EL Finest]: 2010-08-19 13:38:37.437--ServerSession(6419763)--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--property=javax.persistence.jdbc.driver; value=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
[EL Finest]: 2010-08-19 13:38:37.438--ServerSession(6419763)--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--property=javax.persistence.jdbc.url; value=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/chapter02DB
[EL Info]: 2010-08-19 13:38:37.439--ServerSession(6419763)--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.0.v20091127-r5931
[EL Config]: 2010-08-19 13:38:37.46--ServerSession(6419763)--Connection(22664464)--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
    platform=>DerbyPlatform
    user name=> "APP"
    datasource URL=> "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/chapter02DB"
))
[EL Config]: 2010-08-19 13:38:37.857--ServerSession(6419763)--Connection(25782860)--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--Connected: jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/chapter02DB
    User: APP
    Database: Apache Derby  Version: 10.6.1.0 - (938214)
    Driver: Apache Derby Network Client JDBC Driver  Version: 10.6.1.0 - (938214)
[EL Config]: 2010-08-19 13:38:37.857--ServerSession(6419763)--Connection(10594949)--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
    platform=>DerbyPlatform
    user name=> "APP"
    datasource URL=> "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/chapter02DB"
))
[EL Config]: 2010-08-19 13:38:37.863--ServerSession(6419763)--Connection(29499086)--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--Connected: jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/chapter02DB
    User: APP
    Database: Apache Derby  Version: 10.6.1.0 - (938214)
    Driver: Apache Derby Network Client JDBC Driver  Version: 10.6.1.0 - (938214)
[EL Info]: 2010-08-19 13:38:37.885--ServerSession(6419763)--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--file:/home/zakaria/Dev/chapter02/target/classes/_chapter02PU login successful
[EL Finest]: 2010-08-19 13:38:37.933--ServerSession(6419763)--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--End deploying Persistence Unit chapter02PU; session file:/home/zakaria/Dev/chapter02/target/classes/_chapter02PU; state Deployed; factoryCount 1
[EL Finer]: 2010-08-19 13:38:38.004--ServerSession(6419763)--Thread(Thread[com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(),5,com.apress.javaee6.Main])--client acquired
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] An exception occured while executing the Java class. null

Object: Book{id=1231, title='The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy', price=12.5, description='Science fiction comedy series created by Douglas Adams.', isbn='1-84023-742-2', nbOfPage=354, illustrations=false} is not a known entity type.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:346)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:291)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: Book{id=1231, title='The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy', price=12.5, description='Science fiction comedy series created by Douglas Adams.', isbn='1-84023-742-2', nbOfPage=354, illustrations=false} is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4147)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:368)
    at com.apress.javaee6.Main.main(Main.java:30)
    ... 6 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Aug 19 13:38:38 CEST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/68M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[EL Finer]: 2010-08-19 13:38:38.213--UnitOfWork(24128584)--Thread(Thread[Finalizer,8,system])--release unit of work
[EL Finer]: 2010-08-19 13:38:38.214--ClientSession(23817301)--Thread(Thread[Finalizer,8,system])--client released
```

Thak you very much,
Regards.

Comment: please run the mvn command with the -e flag and post the stack trace

Comment: @seanize: I added the error stacktrace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I thought that the problem was the "id=null". But, when I set the Id manually (to 123 for example), I get the same error message.

No, and you're not supposed to set the `Id` when using `GeneratedValue`.

> Anybody has the solution to this error?

The root cause of the problem is that the `BOOK` table doesn't get generated (so EclipseLink can't map the `Book` entity appropriately and then doesn't recognize it as an entity).

This happens because the fully qualified name of the class listed in your `persistence.xml` doesn't match the actual FQN (`com.apress.javaee6.chapter02.Book` vs `com.apress.javaee6.Book`).

So either change the package of the class or the fix the `persistence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="chapter02PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.apress.javaee6.Book</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="DERBY"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/chapter02DB;create=true"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="APP"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="APP"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And running your `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.apress.javaee6.Main"` will succeed:

```
 mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.apress.javaee6.Main" -e
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'exec'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Q3521044 - Maven and the “is not a known entity type” error
[INFO]    task-segment: [exec:java]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Preparing exec:java
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[INFO] [exec:java {execution: default-cli}]
[EL Info]: 2010-08-19 16:39:54.442--ServerSession(2698418)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.0.v20091127-r5931
[EL Info]: 2010-08-19 16:39:55.875--ServerSession(2698418)--file:/home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/Q3521044/target/classes/_chapter02PU login successful
[EL Warning]: 2010-08-19 16:39:56.219--ServerSession(2698418)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.0.v20091127-r5931): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Table/View 'SEQUENCE' already exists in Schema 'APP'.
Error Code: -1
Call: CREATE TABLE SEQUENCE (SEQ_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, SEQ_COUNT DECIMAL(15), PRIMARY KEY (SEQ_NAME))
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="CREATE TABLE SEQUENCE (SEQ_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, SEQ_COUNT DECIMAL(15), PRIMARY KEY (SEQ_NAME))")
[EL Info]: 2010-08-19 16:39:56.574--ServerSession(2698418)--file:/home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/Q3521044/target/classes/_chapter02PU logout successful
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Aug 19 16:39:56 CEST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/88M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But in my opinion, the error is very poorly reported, EclipseLink should report that the table is missing.

#### References

- JPA 1.0 specification

  - 6.2.1.6 mapping-file, jar-file, class, exclude-unlisted-classes

Comment: I'm speechless (or "writelesss" lol). It worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Zakaria: I've spotted the real problem (a mismatch between the real fully qualified name of the Book and the one in the persistence.xml) and have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used EclipseLink myself, so all I can do is guess, but what surprises me is that your class doesn't have a setter for the id property.

I don't know if that's legal according to the JPA specification, but I have never encountered this before. In all JPA applications I know of, all non-transient properties have public getter and setter. (Of course some of them should never be used manually, like the id property, but the Persistence Provider needs them). So try adding a setId() method and we'll take it from there...

Comment: I've already tried to do so. Then, I set the id in the main class manually (I talked about it in this post). But it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of error a lot with Eclipselink.
The only answer I have found is this one, an open bug :

[bug link at eclipse.org](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=288141)

For short, this bug comes from EclipseLink + (osGI) conjoint use, when rebuilding your jar, a pointer to the "old" entity is kept instead of using the new one, hence the error that the entity is unknown. The solution for me was to restart IDE, clean, build, restart my server, install jar/war, run..

Don't know if it's your problem, but it might be...

Comment: I don't think it's a question of "IDE". I use the "IDE" to edit the code. But, for the compile and run operations, I do it with the "mvn" commands.