# Eclipselink -Glassfish project Object is not a known entity type error

Tags: jpa, dependency-injection, eclipselink, entitymanager

In a JSF 2.1 - Spring 3.1  integrated project.I m trying to handle transaction by container i m using eclipselink 2.3.2 ,Glassfish 3.1.2 and Maven on my project and working on Netbeans IDE 7.2 .

At service layer i injected entity manager by the code below and on debug it seems ok .

```
 @Inject
public void setEntityManager() {
EntityManagerFactory emfactory =Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory
("E_DefterManagementPU");
    this.em = emfactory.createEntityManager();
```

But after i filled the entity named **EfaFunctions** and try to persist with

```
em.persist(EfaFunctions);
```

it gives this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@599ebbf6
 is not a known entity type.
```

But in **persistence.xml ** i have following nodes

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>   
<jta-data-source>EFA</jta-data-source>   
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

My entity project location is com.edefter.entity.EfaFunctions ;not the location specified in error .Actually there is an answer written by Pascal [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521044/maven-and-the-is-not-a-known-entity-type-error)
but  my generation strategy is none and my entites were generated  from Database by netbeans .I need some experts advice . Thanks in Advance

I deleted the

```
@Table(name="EFA_FUNCTIONS")
```

annotation from top of Entity ,but @Entity still stays.
The error is gone but then the query starts as

```
INSERT INTO EFAFUNCTIONS
```

without  underscore but i need

```
 INSERT INTO EFA_FUNCTIONS
```

,becouse of it the data did not inserted . Why eclipselink gives error for @Table annotation and despite there is no table like EFAFUNCTIONS why it doesnt give any error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem , As i mentioned  in question i had generated Entities from Database via Netbeans,so that i didn't suspect the entity format.I had worked before hibernate as ORM and hibernate plus DB2 or MYSQL.These combinations didnt give an error with same usage.But with  the combination Eclipselink - Oracle DB **@Entity** annotation has to be parameter as written below

`@Entity(name="entityName")`

`@Table(name="TableName")`

Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you try to persist an EntityManager ? Much better to pass in (to `em.persist`) an Entity (one of those classes tagged as @Entity)

Comment: Sorry for wrong entry  i already give it  an entity  as parameter ;i updated it

Comment: @James I had  given EntityManager object instead of  EfaFunctions on following code . Thanks For your interest  i gues i solved problem 
em.persist(EfaFunctions);

Comment: I m waiting hour restriction i will write reason ,But the problem is not related with your answer  thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, when trying to persist an object of an entity class by calling `persist()` on the entitymanager:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: entities.Documents[ id=null ] is not a known entity type.

it turned out that the name of the persistence unit declared in the persistence.xml in the line

```
<persistence-unit name="my-pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

was diffrent from the name I used when declaring the Entity Manager Factory in the java code:

```
 EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("my-persistenceunit");
```

After correcting both names to the same name, calling `persist()` worked as expected.